# jQuery: .load() method replaces target selector content or appends to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if anyone knows what exactly .load() method does with data it retrieved from url?
Does it replace the target selector content with data retrieved?
OR append that data to the target selector?

Still, it seems to me that .load() method replaces (overrides) the content of the target element...

The documentation is a bit blurry:

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

OR

> .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *replaces* the content. Agreed [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load) could be clearer, although if it were appending I'd expect that to be explicit.

Essentially, and ignoring some details, this:

```
$("selector").load(url);
```

is effectively this:

```
$.get(url, function(html) {
    $("selector").html(html);
});
```

It's a bit more complex if you tell jQuery you only want to load a *fragment* of the returned HTML.

Answer (score 0):

yes it replaces..

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as , , or  elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

Comment: That quote doesn't have to do with what it does with the result. That's talking about how it handles extracting fragments (which is why it's under the "Loading Page Fragments" heading).